# Android location manager error + log file attached

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, locationmanager

I had initially this code in error, Festus helped noted that I have a null location:

```
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

I used Festus GPSTracker class and added used it in my activity as he indicated. Below is my activity class:

```
package com.bob.terranet;

import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Criteria;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Contactus extends Activity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.contactus);

             double latitude = -1, longitude=-1;
              GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(Contactus.this);
              if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                  latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                  longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        }





            String geoUriString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?" + 
                       "saddr=" + latitude + "," +  longitude + "&daddr=" + 33.947917 + "," + 35.645142;





            Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUriString));

                    startActivity(mapCall);
        }



    }
```

The problem is that it is always giving me -1, -1 as location indicating that Network provider is false, while I have network connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the perrmission in the Manifast file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Your `lastKnownLocation` is null and there for you receiving a null pointer exception.

Try this code to get your first location:

```
List<String> matchingProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();
for (String provider: matchingProviders) {
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if (location != null) {
float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
long time = location.getTime();

if ((time > minTime && accuracy < bestAccuracy)) {
  bestResult = location;
  bestAccuracy = accuracy;
  bestTime = time;
}
else if (time < minTime && 
         bestAccuracy == Float.MAX_VALUE && time > bestTime){
  bestResult = location;
  bestTime = time;
}
}
}
```

Taken from here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

I recommend you to read this blog post as well...

basically this code will go over all the available providers to get the best available location.

Comment: Yes I have added them in the Manifest file.

Comment: No I am running it on my android device, with internet connection and google maps shows my location.

Comment: what do you mean Google maps shows your location? I don't see any map in your code.... never the less as @Festus said just check your location is not null before you try to get the lat and lng coordinates.

Comment: I mean when I open Google maps, it gives me my location, so the device is connected to the internet and it is getting my gps location when I open google maps. But It is getting NULL location when I use location manager

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked dozens of times. It is important to note that the GPS and the LocationManager is **event driven** and operates on a **callback** principle. In other words **you get the location when the GPS has got a fix and triggers OnLocationChanged and not before**. You have to wait. It's no good saying I want the location now, because you can't have it. Until OnLocationChanged fires for the first time the getLasKnownLocation will be null and as others have indicated that is the cause of your error.

Comment: Yeah Festus helped me with that, I am trying to figure out now why Network Provider is giving false while I have internet connectivity.